# How to understand the sentence "The instance that A will register itself with once it has been fully configured in B."?

Tags: grammar

> The instance that A will register itself with once it has been fully configured in B.

In my understanding, this sentence can be understand as the following:

> The instance (that A will register itself with) once it has been fully configured in B.

I think `that A will register itself with` is used for decorating `the instance`, but if I remove "(that A will register itself with)", its meaning seems not complete. So I don't understand this structure.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

This sentence come from a python file, its original content is:

> https://gist.github.com/flareriderdash/3ac6423e5ee24ac4df6c4103acf90b49, line 161.
> The :class:`Scheduler <Scheduler>` instance that this job will register itself with once it has been fully configured in :meth:`Job.do()`.

Comment: I don't think it **can** be understood. All it seems to say is, "If something happens after something else." Where did you find it? What is the context? Is it a heading?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thanks, I have added its original content in the modified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the text you have provided is not a sentence on its own. Rather, it is, as @Colin Fine suggested, a noun-phrase being used as a definition. Pulling in the surrounding context from the original you pointed to, then, I think the meaning is as follows:

`:param scheduler:` is defined to be the particular instance of the `Scheduler` class with which any given instance of the `Job` class will register itself, once that instance of `Job` has configured itself with its `Job.do()` method.

Or, more discursively:

When a new instance of class `Job` -- call it `this_job` -- is constructed, it will configure itself using method `Job.do()`. When that is done, `this_job` should then register itself with the specific instance of class `Scheduler` referred to by `:param scheduler:`.

NB: my knowledge of Python is almost non-existent, so please forgive any errors in that respect. I'm trying to answer only the English language question, not one to do with coding.

Comment: Your understanding is absolutely right! Show my respect!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a sentence, as it has no main verb: the whole thing is a noun phrase. It is presumably a definition.

I think that *that A will register itself with once it has been fully configured in B* is a restrictive relative clause, defining which instance is being referred to.

It is possible syntactically that *once it has been fully configured in B* is outside the relative clause, and refers to the instance; but I think it reads more naturally as referring to A.

Comment: Thanks for your help!